# Does Virtuous Recovery help against ongoing damage?

Tags: dnd-4e

Does the feat [Virtuous Recovery](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=1559) help against ongoing damage. If I activate the feat by spending a surge it grants damage reduction equal to my character's wisdom modifier until the start of his next turn. If I'm taking ongoing damage at the time would the feat reduce it at the start of my next turn or will the feat bonus go away before the damage is applied.

Comment: The actual link is http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=1559  I don't have access to fix it myself yet.

Comment: @Pat: Link fixed, but I have to take your word for it—without a DDi subscription it's just a login page.

Comment: Ah, thats too bad.  The link in the OP went to the general compendium link.  Each item uses a layer to appear, so you need to right-click/copy the link to get the direct link to the feat/item needed.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Virtuous Recovery does help against ongoing damage.

It is generally accepted that the player can order the effects in each part of his turn to suit himself.

On p268 of the PH, section entitled "The Start of Your Turn" there are five bullet points.

- Ongoing Damage
- Regeneration
- Other Effects
- End Effects (specifically effects that end automatically at the start of your turn)
- No Actions

Some folks feel that instead of the player determining the order of actions, you need to take them in the order listed.  Either way, your damage reduction is still active in this case.

There has been no errata to this section.

This [post](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/25820897/Interesting_items_from_Rules_Compendium?post_id=465670801#465670801) claims to have information from the Rules Compendium which states explicitly that the player controls the order of start and end of turn effects.  (I have not yet acquired the book myself)

Comment: To me, the key point here, is the "End Effects" ... I don't recall that there are effects that end "at the start of you turn", in which case "until the start of you next turn" effects must be what is meant.

Comment: Sorry, was trying to avoid inserting too much text from the book.  I will clarify.

Comment: Argh, I shoulda searched harder. Thanks for getting it right.

Comment: Lol, no worries!  My group is full of rules lawyers.  We came across this one a while back :)

Comment: I just picked up Heroes of the Fallen Lands, and page 21 confirms that players control the order of start of turn effects. The section doesn't specify for end of turn effects, but I think it'd be reasonable to assume the same applies.

Comment: My shop has a reading copy of the Rules Compendium, so I was able to confirm that as well.